# Display block if content type has entity reference (tags) that contains specific term

Tags: 8, blocks

I want to display a block when a node contains a entity reference field when specific term is present.

I have tried numerous modules that did not work for me or perhaps I did not set them up right, [term_condition](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_condition) [token_conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_conditions) [entity_field_condition](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_field_condition) (using the [appropriate patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_field_condition/issues/2904228))

EDIT: it seems the term_condition works on a clean install after applying some pending patches on the issue queue.  So this probably is a problem with my installation.

Comment: `perhaps I did not set them up right` did you use the **term id** rather than the term name?

Comment: @NoSssweat yes I did try all possible combinations, have you used them are they working or perhaps there is something in my system that prevents them from working ? I am working with block visibility groups module perhaps something is wrong with that ?

Comment: term_condition worked; although, it's buggy. When I try to configure the block after setting term ID visiblity, I'm getting an error. But as far as displaying the block goes, it works as expected. **Note** I am testing on a fresh install.

Comment: It looks like term_condition is exactly what you want. There are some pending patches that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably [term_condition](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_condition)

Install/enable the module and then on the block layout of a certain block you will be presented with a *term visibility setting* where you can search for term that will be used as the visibility condition.

[image]

**NOTE:** Currently the module is incompatible with rules as rules has its numerous conditions on its own.  This issue has been reported [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_condition/issues/2979866)